# Firebase Cloud Functions Very Slow

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm on the free tier of Firebase and I have a cloud function that is triggered by a realtime database write. The function then downloads a file from Firebase Storage (~8 Mb), does some processing, and writes back to the realtime database. I've added some logging statements throughout the function to figure out why it was taking so long.

- The function is triggered immediately (good).
- The file takes about 3 minutes to download (bad).
- The processing takes about 20 minutes to complete (uh, what?)

The function finishes in < 10 seconds when I run it locally. **Why does it take so incredibly long inside of a cloud function?**

**functions/index.js**

```
exports.doStuff = functions.database.ref('/my/path/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
  const implementation = require('./implementation');

  // Variables omitted for brevity...

  implementation.process(...variables);

  return true;
});
```

**functions/implementation.js**

```
function process(...variables) {
  const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const storage = new Storage();

  // Variables omitted for brevity...

  const options = {
    destination: tempFilePath,
  };

  storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .file(srcFilename)
    .download(options)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('This takes 3+ minutes for an 8 Mb file');
      doStuffWithDownloadedFile(tempFilePath);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('ERROR: ', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using.  Without that, it's all guessing.

Comment: @DougStevenson The processing code is pretty complex so it would take some effort to distill it down into a sample. In the meantime, I've added the code I'm using to download, which takes longer than I would expect for an 8 Mb file.

Comment: @DougStevenson Is this because I'm returning true instead of a Promise?

Comment: Things can go wrong if you don't return a promise from a non-https type function.  That's by far the most common issue among all functions that aren't working as intended. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions